# Error on update of data

Tags: java, sql, jdbc

When I change the data of some field and click on update button it showing record not found

message

its a total o/p
init:
Deleting: F:\sanskar1\build\built-jar.properties
deps-jar:
Updating property file: F:\sanskar1\build\built-jar.properties
compile:
run:

Driver loaded
Hi
SeniorPerson: dude
RegistrationNo: 36
NativePlace: nasik
Kul: balaji
Gotra: fg
KulSwami: gfgf
ResidensialAddress: gfgfg
PinCode: 2345673
STDcode: 4343
TelephoneNo: 2345673
MobileNo: 1234567891
Email: fdsf@
Website: fsdfwww
Education: fghgfh
Branch: hgfhfh
BloodGroup: O+ve

Driver loaded
statement is created
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 1 minute 3 seconds)

my code is:

```
   int regno1= Integer.parseInt(cbregn.getSelectedItem().toString());
//          //int regno1= Integer.parseInt((String)cbregn.getSelectedItem());
          if(cbregn.getSelectedItem().toString().equals(""))
          JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null," ENTER THE REGISTRATION NO ");
//
//          String regno1= cbregn.getSelectedItem().toString();
//          if(regno1.equals("")){
//          JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null," ENTER THE REGISTRATION NO ");
//           return;
      // }

             try
             {
              Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
              System.out.println("\n Driver loaded");
              Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:wanisamajDB");
              Statement stmt=con.createStatement();
              System.out.println("statement is created");
                // System.out.println(Integer.parseInt(cbregn.getSelectedItem().toString()));
              String qry= " UPDATE Registration1 set RegistrationNo = '"+cbregn.getSelectedItem()+"',SeniorPerson = '"+cbnm.getSelectedItem()+"', NativePlace = '"+tfplace.getText()+"', Kul = '"+tfkul.getText()+"', Gotra = '"+tfgotra.getText()+"' ,KulSwami = '"+tfswami.getText()+"', ResidensialAddress = '"+taraddr.getText()+"' , PinCode = '"+Integer.parseInt(tfpcd.getText())+"', STDcode = '"+Integer.parseInt(tfstdcode.getText())+"', TelephoneNo = '"+Integer.parseInt(tftele.getText())+"', MobileNo = '"+(int) Long.parseLong(tfmno.getText())+"', Email = '"+tfemail.getText()+"',Website ='"+tfweb.getText()+"',Education ='"+tfedu.getText()+"',Branch ='"+tfbrch.getText()+"',BloodGroup ='"+cbbldgrp.getSelectedItem().toString()+"' where RegistrationNo='" +Integer.parseInt(cbregn.getSelectedItem().toString())+"'" ;
             // String qry= " UPDATE Registration1 set SeniorPerson = '"+cbnm.getSelectedItem().toString()+"',NativePlace = '"+tfplace.getText()+"', Kul = '"+tfkul.getText()+"',Gotra = '"+tfgotra.getText()+"' , KulSwami = '"+tfswami.getText()+"', ResidensialAddress = '"+taraddr.getText()+"' , PinCode = '"+Integer.parseInt(tfpcd.getText())+"', STDcode = '"+Integer.parseInt(tfstdcode.getText())+"',TelephoneNo = '"+Integer.parseInt(tftele.getText())+"',MobileNo = '"+Integer.parseInt(tfmno.getText())+"',Email = '"+tfemail.getText()+"',Website ='"+tfweb.getText()+"',Education ='"+tfedu.getText()+"',Branch ='"+tfbrch.getText()+"',BloodGroup ='"+cbbldgrp.getSelectedItem().toString()+"' where RegistrationNo='" +Integer.parseInt(cbregn.getSelectedItem().toString())+"'" ;
              stmt.executeUpdate(qry);
              JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"RECORD IS UPDATED SUCCESSFULLY ");
              System.out.println("QUERY");       

              cbregn.setEditable(false);
              cbnm.setEditable(false);
              tfplace.setEditable(false);
              tfkul.setEditable(false);
              tfgotra.setEditable(false);
              tfswami.setEditable(false);
              taraddr.setEditable(false);
              tfpcd.setEditable(false);
              tfstdcode.setEditable(false);
              tftele.setEditable(false);
              tfmno.setEditable(false);
              tfemail.setEditable(false);
              tfweb.setEditable(false);
              tfedu.setEditable(false);
              tfbrch.setEditable(false);
              cbbldgrp.setEditable(false);
              con.close();
              stmt.close();
            }
            catch(SQLException eM)
            {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"RECORD IS NOT FOUND ");
            }
            catch(Exception et)
            {
            System.out.println("error:"+et.getMessage());
            }
```

Comment: If you add a stacktrace people might be able to help better...

Comment: You should be using prepared statements as they will take care of the escaping and quoting of parameters as well as prevent sql injection attacks.

Answer (score 0):

When creating the connection, don't you need to set username and password?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like an exception is being thrown at the line where your create your qry String.  I think you're attempting to create a type using a null or empty String based on the exception message...

> "For input string"

I'd strongly suggest debugging the qry = ... line and checking the values of all the fields your converting to String objects, one of them is null.  You may also want to print the stack trace (et.printStackTace()) in your catch block to confirm the problem.